# Changing the colors of 9 patch chat bubbles

Tags: java, android

I am working on a chat application, the chat bubbles are 9 patch images and i want to change their color.can i change the color of a 9 patch chat bubble?

Comment: see `Drawable#setColorFilter()` method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - 9 patch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006633/android-9-patch)

Answer (score 0):

Changed the color of the drawable before returing as

```
Drawable myIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.bubble_blue_right);
ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter( Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
myIcon.setColorFilter(filter);
```